# postfix logging message-id for a specific error - Message size exceeds fixed limit

Tags: postfix, logging

In postfix log, I need to log the message-id when postfix returns the following error: 
Sep 27 22:45:48 pf-test-h1 postfix/smtpd[25435]: NOQUEUE: reject: MAIL from unknown[192.168.125.47]: 552 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed limit;

Is is possible to achieve this?
I tried with headerchecks and it only logs for other types of message status (Success/failures) but not for this particular.  Any ideas?